# form submission to database upon payment been completed via paypal

Tags: php, forms, paypal

OK. I have my connection to my database allowing content to be posted to my website from users.

I'm missing a key function that will allow me to charge users before they post a posting to my website.

I have been searching for a course or solution example for weeks now and have been unsuccessful. Can anyone help me or lead me in the right direction?

Here is an example:

[dummydata form image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GURmQ.png)

This will work to take you to a payment portal but will not submit my form data to database after payment is complete. If I change action to action="" the data will be sent to my database but no payment will be required.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please add some code for reference.

Comment: When the payment is complete in PayPal, you have to send them back to a page on your site that will do the rest of the processing. I think it's a setting within PayPal. See https://www.paypal.com/us/smarthelp/article/how-do-i-use-paypal's-auto-return-feature-to-redirect-customers-back-to-my-website-faq3651

Comment: so how would I combine the submit button with the button that takes them to the PayPal? I'm confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three essential steps:

1. collect and verify payment
2. collect content to be posted/displayed
3. enable post for display on website

Steps (1) and (2), the collection steps, can happen in either order. And probably sequentially, one right after the other. But importantly, they **CANNOT** happen simultaneously. They are separate processes that occur one after the other.

Comment: Do you have an example of the code or instructional video I can watch. I'm using PHP. Like how to you collect the data before sending it to the database. How would you enable the post to display? I would like to learn how this is accomplished.

Comment: There are many ways to design such an application, so I will just give one example. You could have a form that collects all the data and saves it directly to the database, but there will be a column called "paid" that defaults to "false".  When this is false, the post does not show up for display.  After submitting that form, the user is given a private direct link to view the post, and where they can pay for it to be displayed.

Comment: You can collect payment with an integration like this one (simple client-side javascript): https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client -- or with javascript that calls your own server-side endpoints that do API calls to PayPal, if you need more security: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: Once a payment checks out, you change the "paid" column to "true" and the post shows up on your site.

Comment: It might be easiest to build something like this in a CMS such as Drupal or Wordpress rather than from scratch. YMMV

Comment: Preston PHX. Thank you. I have integrated stripe and everything works. The only problem now is that the post will go through even if the payment is canceled, incomplete or closed out before processed. Currently looking for a solution to how or where to implement an if statement.